# FFMPEG: Changing the filter prevents the video from being blurred

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am new to FFMPEG, it has been a few days I am working on it. I tried the code given at 
[FFmpeg - Apply blur over face](https://superuser.com/questions/901099/ffmpeg-apply-blur-over-face)
 .I have a video with `208 X 208` resolution and I need to blur a rectangle on the video, with some width/height and top/left offset. The following codes successfully blur the video

`ffmpeg -i test1.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=10:10:1:1,boxblur=1[b0];[0:v][b0]overlay=10:10" intro-blur.mov`

`ffmpeg -i test1.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=50:50:1:1,boxblur=1[b0];[0:v][b0]overlay=10:10" intro-blur.mov`

**But the followings don't**

`ffmpeg -i test1.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=5:5:1:1,boxblur=10[b0];[0:v][b0]overlay=10:10" intro-blur.mov`

`ffmpeg -i test1.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=10:10:1:1,boxblur=10[b0];[0:v][b0]overlay=10:10" intro-blur.mov`

`ffmpeg -i test1.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=20:20:1:1,boxblur=10[b0];[0:v][b0]overlay=10:10" intro-blur.mov`

I would like to know why it is so? What is the problem with the codes that don't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [boxblur](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#boxblur) says,

> The radius value must be a non-negative number, and must not be
>   greater than the value of the expression min(w,h)/2 for the luma and
>   alpha planes, and of min(cw,ch)/2 for the chroma planes.

and

> If not specified, chroma_radius and alpha_radius default to the
>   corresponding value set for luma_radius.

---

So, in `crop=20:20:1:1,boxblur=10`

for the luma plane condition, the value `10` should equal to or be less than `min(20,20)/2` = `10`.  PASS

But since you haven't specified a value for the chroma radius, it evaluates to `20`. Now, most videos are YUV 4:2:0 i.e. the chroma planes' width and height is half that of the luma plane, so in `crop=20:20:1:1,boxblur=10`,

for the chroma plane, the value `10` should equal to or be less than `min(10,10)/2` = `5`.  FAIL!

The remedy is to either ensure the radius value satisfies the conditions, or insert a format filter before the blur.

`crop=20:20:1:1,format=yuv444p,boxblur=10`

You still have to make sure that the blur radius is equal to or less than half the smallest dimension of the cropped area.

Comment: Hey @gyan,when i'm using boxblur, its showing me error Invalid chroma_param radius value 25, must be >= 0 and <= 15 when blur area is small,is there any solution for that?